# query with like clause in scalikejdbc

Tags: scalikejdbc

Can anyone please give me a example for how to use like clause in scalikejdbc with dynamic value. I used following query but it did not work

```
 sql"select * from tables_list where lower(TABLE_NAME) like '%$tableName.toLowerCase%'"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

scalikejdbc build in prevent sql injection, therefore when you type `like '%$tableName.toLowerCase%'`, it appear as `like '%'urValue'%'`, hence error occur.

I found a way to go ground it, which is

```
def search(name:String){
    val searchName = s"%$name%"
    DB readOnly{ implicit session =>
        sql"select * from db where name like $searchName".map
    ...
    ...
}
```

I hope this can help you.